# What is the basic difference between namespace , library and header files?

Tags: header, namespaces, terminology

I was searching on the internet about the differences between namespace , header file and library but I am still confused that what is the basic difference between them , please give an answer in the context of programming language not any specific language like C or C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Namespace**

A namespace is a declarative region that provides a scope to the identifiers (the names of types, functions, variables, etc) inside it. Namespaces are used to organize code into logical groups and to prevent name collisions that can occur especially when your code base includes multiple libraries.

**Library**

In programming, a library is a collection of precompiled routines that a program can use. The routines, sometimes called modules, are stored in object format. Libraries are particularly useful for storing frequently used routines because you do not need to explicitly link them to every program that uses them.

**Header Files**

Header files contain definitions of Functions and Variables, which is imported or used into any C++ program by using the pre-processor #include statement. Header file have an extension ".h" which contains C++ function declaration and macro definition.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

libraries contain predefined function definitions.
header files contain predefined function declaration means prototypes and also contains macros as well
When ever we install some compiler,we select the suitable version of compiler that our OS supports that means every compiler has some set of library functions where OS uses them for I/O.